# Script to update xml value

Tags: xml, linux, xslt, awk, gawk

I am trying to do update on xml file based on condition using AWK Script. Could anyone assist me on this?

**students.xml**

```
<students>
    <student>
        <stuId>1</stuId>
        <name>A</name>
        <mark>75</mark>
        <result></result>
    </student>
    <student>
        <stuId>2</stuId>
        <name>B</name>
        <mark>35</mark>
        <result></result>
    </student>
    <student>
        <stuId>1</stuId>
        <name>C</name>
        <mark>94</mark>
        <result></result>
    </student>
</students>
```

**Code I tried so far**

I am able to extract tag values using below code

```
BEGIN { RS="<[^>]+>" } 
{ print  RT, $0 }
```

This prints all the tag and values as expected.

I want to update the `<result>` tag as **pass** if **marks > 40** else **fail**

**Output**

```
<students>
    <student>
        <stuId>1</stuId>
        <name>A</name>
        <mark>75</mark>
        <result>pass</result>
    </student>
    <student>
        <stuId>2</stuId>
        <name>B</name>
        <mark>35</mark>
        <result>fail</result>
    </student>
    <student>
        <stuId>1</stuId>
        <name>C</name>
        <mark>94</mark>
        <result>pass</result>
    </student>
</students>
```

Could any one assist me on this?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes it does. I'm taking this sample approach to actual implementation hope it works there. I'll let you know if I faced any issues there. Thanks all again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to parse XML with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), instead use a real parser :

[image: warning] the XML file is edited *on the fly*!

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# edit file.xml file in place
use strict; use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $xl = XML::LibXML->new();
my $xml = $xl->load_xml(location => '/tmp/file.xml') ;

for my $node ($xml->findnodes('//student/result')) {
    my $mark = $node->findnodes('../mark/text()')->string_value;
    $node->removeChildNodes();
    if ($mark > 40) {
        $node->appendText('pass');
    }
    else {
        $node->appendText('fail');
    }
}

$xml->toFile('/tmp/file.xml');
```

### Modified file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<students>
  <student>
    <stuId>1</stuId>
    <name>A</name>
    <mark>75</mark>
    <result>pass</result>
  </student>
  <student>
    <stuId>2</stuId>
    <name>B</name>
    <mark>35</mark>
    <result>fail</result>
  </student>
  <student>
    <stuId>1</stuId>
    <name>C</name>
    <mark>94</mark>
    <result>pass</result>
  </student>
</students>
```

Comment: Nice perl parsing solution  +1! This time as I have also judged that this was a parser solution that would be the best, I have proposed a XSLT solution! Bonne nuit au fait ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to use the [`ed` (edit) command](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139594320) of [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html)...

```
xmlstarlet ed -L -u "//student[mark >= 40]/result" -v "pass" -u "//student[40 > mark]/result" -v "fail" students.xml
```

***CAUTION:*** The `-L` in the command line will edit the file inplace. Be sure to remove it if that is not the behavior you want.

You can also use XSLT 1.0 with xmlstartlet (the [`tr` (transform) command](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139602800))...

**update.xsl**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="student[mark >= 40]/result">
    <xsl:copy>pass</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="student[40 > mark]/result">
    <xsl:copy>fail</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**command line**

```
xmlstarlet tr update.xsl students.xml
```

Answer (score 4):

I would also recommend to avoid a `XML parser/processor` approach here:
If you don't like `perl` you can use a full XML technology approach by using `XSLT`:

**INPUT:**

```
$ more students.xml
::::::::::::::
students.xml
::::::::::::::
<students>
    <student>
        <stuId>1</stuId>
        <name>A</name>
        <mark>75</mark>
        <result></result>
    </student>
    <student>
        <stuId>2</stuId>
        <name>B</name>
        <mark>35</mark>
        <result></result>
    </student>
    <student>
        <stuId>1</stuId>
        <name>C</name>
        <mark>94</mark>
        <result></result>
    </student>
</students>
```

**XSLT stylesheet:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform (copy everything) -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- when you reach result take action-->
<xsl:template match="result">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                        <!-- fetch the value of mark of the parent node -->
                        <xsl:variable name="mark" select="../mark" />
                        <xsl:choose>
                        <!-- if over 40 -->
                         <xsl:when test="$mark > 40">
                           <xsl:text>pass</xsl:text>
                         </xsl:when>
                         <!-- else -->
                         <xsl:otherwise>
                           <xsl:text>fail</xsl:text>
                         </xsl:otherwise>
                   </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>   
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**COMMAND:**

```
$ xsltproc --output students_grade.xml students.xsl  students.xml
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
more students_grade.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<students>
  <student>
    <stuId>1</stuId>
    <name>A</name>
    <mark>75</mark>
    <result>pass</result>
  </student>
  <student>
    <stuId>2</stuId>
    <name>B</name>
    <mark>35</mark>
    <result>fail</result>
  </student>
  <student>
    <stuId>1</stuId>
    <name>C</name>
    <mark>94</mark>
    <result>pass</result>
  </student>
</students>
```